# why I am not getting output for prims algorithm in python?

Tags: python

```
 def prims():
        r = 3;
        c = 3;
        total = 0
        matrix = [ [0 for x in range(r)] for y in range(c)]
        min = 999
    u = 0
    v = 0
    visited = [i for i in range(3)]
    for i in range(0,3):
            for j in range(0,3):
                matrix[i][j] = input()
                if matrix[i][j]== 0:
                    matrix[i][j] = 999
    visited[0] = 1
    for counter in range(0,5):
        min = 999
        for i in range(0,3):
            if visited[i] == 1:
                for j in range(0,3):
                    if visited[j] != 1 :
                        if min > matrix[i][j]:
                            min = matrix[i][j]
                            u = i
                            v = j
        visited[v] = 1
        total = total + min
        print("edge found :"+u+"->"+v+":weight" %(min))
    print("The weight of minimum spanning tree is : " %total)
   # print matrix
    return
    enter code here

prims()
```

why I am not getting output for above code???

```
 File "prims.py", line 31, in prims
    print("edge found :"+u+"->"+v+":weight" %(min))
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Comment: do proper string formatting. you should either use `"edge found :"+str(u)` or `"edge found {}:".format(u)`. try to understand the error it clearly says you are concatenating string and integer

Comment: Please fix your indentation. In python it is very relevant how much each line of code is indented!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add an integer to a string in your first print statement, and in the second you are not outputting total anywhere in the string. Try this:

```
print("edge found :{}->{}:{}".format(u,v,min))
print("The weight of minimum spanning tree is : {}".format(total))
```